# GCMIntentService won't run on android 2.3.4

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging, registration

I'm on Google clouding message app that works on 4+ android devices. but the  **GCMIntentService**
service wont run on my sony xperia arc that have android 2.3 and so it will not register to GCM. I also should say that my xperia arc is rooted. is rooting the problem? my project is customization of this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

I creates check points in **GCMIntentService** but it wont run at all.
this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <permission
        android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- mahdi comments: for registration of reciver for GCM  -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".global.G">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.mypackagename" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.mypackagename.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Try the service using the 2.3.3 emulator, which is still available on the SDK Manager. It's going to prove difficult to solve your issue because 1) you have a rooted device, and 2), you are using deprecated c2dm classes.

Comment: @Koh it's not work on emulator cause there is no google account on it